# Knock Out ObservableArray aync call binding order issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, knockout.js

I have a ObservableArray.Using ajax async calls I am fetching data for binding.There will be 1000's of data. In each calls will fetch 100's of data. Problem is due to ajax async call order will not be from 1 - 1000. Cannot make it as sync call because browser will not respond. How can i sort the async data in knock out?

```
var DataVM = ko.observableArray([]);
ko.applyBindings(DataVM, document.getElementById("ControlBlock"));

for (var i = 0; i < totalAjaxCall; i++) {
                        GetData(guid, start, end, self.DataCallback);
                        start = start + 100;
                        end = end +100;
                    }

 DataCallback= function (result) {
        var temp = JSON.parse(result.d); 
        var data = [];
        var data = temp.Data;
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            var tempItem_ = new Item();
            tempItem_.Number = data[j].Number;
        // Other codes           
            DataVM.push(tempItem_ );
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remember the blocks as they come in, then reassemble things when you've received them all. See comments:

```
var DataVM = ko.observableArray([]);
ko.applyBindings(DataVM, document.getElementById("ControlBlock"));

// Remember the results in a temporary array of arrays
var received = 0;
var receivedBlocks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < totalAjaxCall; i++) {
    // Tell `DataCallback` which block it's going to get
    GetData(guid, start, end, self.DataCallback.bind(null, i));
    // No need for `self` ----^^^^^
    start = start + 100;
    end = end +100;
}

DataCallback = function (i, result) {
    // Create and remember the items for this block
    receivedBlocks[i] = JSON.parse(result.d).map(function(e) {
        var tempItem_ = new Item();
        tempItem_.Number = num;
        return tempItem_;
    });
    ++received;

    // Do we have them all?
    if (received == totalAjaxCall) {
        // Flatten our array of arrays, now we have all the pieces
        var receivedItems = []
        receivedBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
            receivedItems.push.apply(result, block);
        });

        // Push all of those onto DataVM as a single operation
        // Note: You were using `DataVM.push`, so I used that here,
        // but if you wanted to *replace* the contents of `DataVM`,
        // (or if you know it's empty), you'd just do:
        //      DataVM(receivedItems);
        // instead.
        DataVM.push.apply(DataVM, receivedItems);
    }
};
```

Comment: @How the sorting will happens?

Comment: It's handled by the way we build `receivedBlocks`: Note that we're passing `DataCallback` the index of the block (`i`), and then using that to populate `receivedBlocks`: `receivedBlocks[i] = ...`. So it doesn't matter if block 3 comes in before block 2, we store it in the right place in `receivedBlocks`. (Arrays can have holes in them in JavaScript, they're inherently *sparse*.) So when we know we have all the blocks, we know all of the slots in `receivedBlocks` have been filled in, in order.

Comment: This will load all the 1000 data at the same time ?

Comment: @James: It fills in the observable array all at once at the end, yes, when all the pieces have been retrieved. We could fill it in incrementally if we wanted.

Comment: User need to see first 100 first

Comment: @James: Well, you didn't say that, did you? :-) But it's possible to show partial results if you want, just tweak the code a bit. All the pieces are there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how far you want to deviate from your current code, but I'd like to advertise some of knockout's additional features :)

If you create a small "in-between" model for your requests, you can make use of  `computed` values to automatically keep track of a correctly sorted list of data.

For example, if you define a `new Request()` like so:

```
var Request = function(start, end) {
  this.completed = ko.observable(false);
  this.data = [];

  getData(start, end, this.onLoad.bind(this));
};

Request.prototype.onLoad = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.completed(true);
};
```

You can change your `for` loop to create those "in-between" models. This creates a `Request` for `0` to `100`, `101` to `201`, etc. Each of these models is stored in an array, in the order of creation.

```
function getDataRequests(start, end, chunkSize) {
  var requests = [];
  for (var i = start; i < end; i += chunkSize) {
    requests.push(new Request(i, Math.min(i + chunkSize, end)));
  }
  return requests;
};
```

Now that you can create an ordered array, you can compute another ordered array of `data` by merging all `completed` requests together:

```
var DataVM = function(start, end, chunkSize) {
  // We keep track of a list of requests
  var requests = ko.observableArray(
    getDataRequests(start, end, chunkSize)
  );

  // Because requests have an observable completed prop,
  // we can automatically keep track of a list of completed
  // requests
  var completedRequests = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    requests().filter(r => r.completed()));

  // Now, whenever a requests completes, we flatten the 
  // `data` parts for `completed` requests
  this.data = ko.pureComputed(() => completedRequests()
    .reduce((items, r) => items.concat(r.data), []));
};
```

Because you have the `requests` array, you can easily compute UI properties. For example: `firstLoaded` is a computed that returns the `completed` value of your *first* request.

Here's a complete example (ES2015):

```js
var DataVM = function(start, end, chunkSize) {
  // We keep track of a list of requests
  var requests = ko.observableArray(
    getDataRequests(start, end, chunkSize)
  );

  // Because requests have an observable completed prop,
  // we can automatically keep track of a list of completed
  // requests
  var completedRequests = ko.pureComputed(() =>
                                          requests().filter(r => r.completed()));

  // Now, whenever a requests completes, we flatten the 
  // `data` parts for `completed` requests
  this.data = ko.pureComputed(() => completedRequests()
                              .reduce((items, r) => items.concat(r.data), []));

  // Shows progress
  this.loadingMsg = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    var completedCount = completedRequests().length,
       allCount = requests().length;

    return completedCount === allCount 
     ? `Done loading ${end - start} items in ${allCount} steps` 
      : `Loading... (${completedCount}/${allCount})`;
  });

  // Check if the first (if any) request has completed loading
  this.firstCompleted = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    requests().length && requests()[0].completed());
};


var Request = function(start, end) {
  this.completed = ko.observable(false);
  this.data = [];

  getData(start, end, this.onLoad.bind(this));
};

Request.prototype.onLoad = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.completed(true);
};

var vm = new DataVM(0, 50, 5);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Mock async ajax stuff and data getters
function getDataRequests(start, end, chunkSize) {
  var requests = [];
  for (var i = start; i < end; i += chunkSize) {
    requests.push(new Request(i, Math.min(i + chunkSize, end)));
  }
  return requests;
};

function getData(start, end, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   cb(mockData(start, end));
  }, Math.random() * 3000 + 500);
}

function mockData(from, to) {
 return Array(to - from).fill(from).map(function(_, i) {
      return from + i;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: loadingMsg"></div>

<ul data-bind="foreach: data, visible: firstCompleted" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```